# No cycles in finite coxeter graphs

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, coxeter-groups

Is there an elementary (no consideration of root systems involved) proof of the fact that the graph of an finite coxeter system doesn't entail any cycle? I got as far as this: If there were any cycle $s_1,\dots,s_p$, consider the element $s_1\dots s_p$. It's probably going to be of infinite order (but I can't say why) and therefore the coxeter group isn't finite. Alternatively, $(s_1\dots s_p)^r$ could yield to elements of increasing length contradicting the fact that finite coxeter groups entail an element of maximal length.

Comment: I don't think that there is likely to be a very elementary way of doing this. First you need the property of Coxeter groups that the group defined by the subgraph induced on a subset of vertices embeds into the original group, and then you need the fact that the Coxeter groups corresponding to loops are infinite. This includes as a special case the result for $3$ vertices, that the group $\langle x,y \mid x,y \mid x^l=y^m=(xy)^n=1 \rangle$ is infinite whenever $l,m,n \ge 3$.

Comment: According to Bjorner/Brenti, Combinatorics of Coxeter Groups, p. 22 Ex. 4 it is possible.